# C# e.HasMorePage fica em Loop Eterno

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou criando um sistema para impressão de etiquetas como segue o código:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Image newImage;
    Point ulCorner;
    int x = 0;
    int xn = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int yn = 0;
    bool xativo = false;

    int n = 14;
    int n1 = 0;
    int yPage = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < lstAdesivos.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        newImage = Image.FromFile(@path + "\\Modelos\\" + lstAdesivos.Items[i].Text + ".png");
        if (xativo == true)
        {
            x = 400;
            y = 0;
            xativo = false;
        }

        ulCorner = new Point(x, y);
        yPage += newImage.Size.Height;

        if (yPage > e.PageBounds.Height)
        {
            e.HasMorePages = true;
            yPage = 0;
        }

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, ulCorner);

        if (yn == nudCartelasColuna.Value - 1)
        {
            yn = 0;
            xativo = true;
        }
        else
        {
            y += 200;
            yn += 1;
        }
    }

    Font fonte = new Font("Verdana", 12);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(tbDescricao.Text, fonte, Brushes.Black, 400, 1050);
}
```

O que acontece é que ao invés de criar apenas uma nova página ele fica criando muitas infinitamente, gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Aonde a variável "e" é declarada? Essa trecho de código está dentro de algum evento? isso seria windows forms, wpf, asp.net, asp.net MVC? seja mais específico por favor. Dê também uma olhada nessa página [ask]

Comment: Win Form, fica dentro do printDocument1_PrintPage(), alterei o código la em cima.

Answer (score 1):

É um problema de lógica isso, acho que você não entendeu bem como o processo de impressão funciona com o PrintDocument.

Como você disse ele entra de novo no `PrintPage`, e isso é o esperado.

Este evento, `PrintPage` vai ser chamado uma vez para cada página, se quando ele terminar de executar o valor de `e.HasMorePages` for igual a `true` ele vai ser chamado novamente.

O que você precisa é saber quais imagens já foram impressas cada vez que o evento for chamado.

Basicamente você imprime o que cabe na página, a hora que não cabe mais só que ainda existem mais coisas para serem impressas você seta o `e.HasMorePages = true` e sai da função, então ela vai ser chamada novamente e você continua imprimindo o que falta na nova página de onde parou, repetindo o processo se necessário.

Como fazer isso existem diversas formas, provavelmente você vai precisar de algum valor no escopo da classe para marcar onde parou e saber de onde continuar.

Answer (score 0):

Meu "chute" é que a cada iteração do bloco vc está aumentando o lstAdesivo.items.count, seria possível? Não vi a definição dela no código e arrisco que se vc está num loop infinito, a cada  iteração o count sobe uma unidade. Pode testar e reportar?

Olhando por cima, seu código não me parece errado, por isso é a única coisa que me ocorre.

Answer (score 0):

Então o for está funcionando normalmente, mas uma coisa que percebi é que após terminar o for ele começa novamente o printDocument1_PrintPage. Então entra no for novamente.

Estou chamando dessa forma:

printPreviewDialog1.Document = this.printDocument1;

printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();

Answer (score 0):

Tenta ai

```
    if (yPage > e.PageBounds.Height)
    {
        e.HasMorePages = true;
        yPage = 0;
    }else{
        e.HasMorePages = true;

    }
```